# Inserting files via automation in Premiere Pro

Tags: script, automation, macros, adobe-premiere

I'd like to have a way to automate creating a sequence, inserting two video segments, and then inserting another piece of video in-between that changes each time (the previous two segments are always the same).

Here's an image:

[image]

Is there any way to do at least part of the process? As in, is it possible to match up videos (with separate audio files) to sequences?

Comment: Couldn't you overwrite the actual footage used for the middle part? Premiere will simply take the new file's contents.

Comment: Yes, I could overwrite the middle part, but I'm looking for a way for that it would automatically just run through the different files and do this. It sounds like I'm being lazy, but I have to do this for hundreds of files (gameplay footage). Basically, a way to match up the sequence and the footage, so it will just run through it. (any way to do any scripts/addons/macros for Premiere Pro CS6?)

Comment: @slhck Thanks for the idea, also, how could I 'overwrite'? I've tried "Replace with Clip" -> "From Bin" but the issue with that is it only replaces the length of the offline file. If the offline file is too short, then it cuts the footage; if it's too long, I have to press ripple delete. If I can find a way to overwrite it directly (with the same length), I might be able to use AutoHotKey to do it.

Comment: I see… I meant replacing the actual file that's on your hard drive, but that's not going to help much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use Adobe Extenscript Toolkit CC.  No documentation listed for Premiere Pro, but if you run ESTK CC you can view the data objects in premiere to write your code.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, could you provide more information as how this fits OP's needs